# Does i18next work on cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, i18next

I am making an app with Angular 1.5.3 and I know that the i18next library works with Angular. https://www.i18next.com/supported-frameworks.html

However, does this still apply if my angular app will be run inside of Cordova?

Comment: Sure...runs on every js env. react-native, electron, ionic...whatever

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use angular-translate which can be found at this link: [Angular Translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) . I used it with a lot of Ionic projects. Thats works like a charm